# Disable device lock when pressing Gnex power button

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-nexus

When I press the power button on my Galaxy Nexus to turn off the screen, it immediately locks the phone, and I have to enter my code the next time I turn the screen back on.  However, if I let the screen timeout and turn itself off, I don't have to enter my code when I turn it back on.

This is highly annoying.  I'd prefer the device to only lock after a period of inactivity.  What's the best way to make that happen?

Comment: You may want to take a closer look at the settings of your Nexus. Some devices offer different settings for delays of turning device-lock on ("Timeout"). Especially if you're running a CustomROM, chances are good (e.g. CyanogenMod offers these options). As they are always at different places, it's hard to say where to look: security is a likely place, and with CM it's in the CyanogenMod submenu.

Answer (score 4):

Stock ICS and Jelly Bean already support this option.  Go to *Settings* > *Security* and uncheck the *Power button instantly locks* option.  Now, your phone will lock only after the desired period of inactivity.

Note, you may have to set the *Automatically lock* option to something other than "Instantly" in order to get the delayed lock.